error in stlink utility
I am having difficulty connecting the ST-LINK/V2 to my microcontroller. An error appears in the ST-LINK utility. I have already verified all the connections, including the decoupling capacitor, all the pin connections, power supply connections, and USB drivers, but I am still unable to resolve the error. Here, I have attached my connections with ST-LINK pin numbers. Can anyone please help me solve this error?



You said you have verified the connections. But we don't know what connectios they are. Is it a genuine ST-Link or a clone? Is your target MCU powered up from somewhere?

Thanks for your reply. I am using STLINK V2 Clone. I tried both giving external power supply and powering from STLINK but that also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

@NidhiSayanja - Hi, You posted an "answer" (which was actually not an answer, and has therefore been deleted) using a second account with the same username. Please note that this causes problems for you since, despite having the same username, a second account of yours which did not post the question, cannot properly interact on this question e.g. a second account cannot write a comment or accept an answer here, since that account will not have the privileges that the account used to write the original question does have. || Please use only this account here. TY

You are not supposed to use pin 19, it is not a standard to have 3.3V output.
And you need to use pin 1 to MCU VDD, or the ST-Link cannot communicate with the MCU.
So you have basically swapped pin 19 and 1.
If your board is not powered and consumes very little, you may use pin 19, but it is non-standard and you should power the MCU separately, not from ST-Link.

Thanks for your reply. I am using STLINK V2 Clone so I am not getting any output from pin one in STLINK. I also tried giving external power supply to the MCU and also created a common ground but that also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

You are not supposed to get output from pin 1, it is an input on a real ST-Link. And of course you need ground so if you did not have it before then there may be some damage. We don't know which clone you have so you need to ask the seller how to use it. Expecting clones to work may be too optimistic

If it's not a /real/ STLink, that's also relevant information to add in the original post, tbh.
